# What does the JUnit 4 @Test Annotation actually do

Tags: testing, junit, junit4

What does the @Test actually do?  I have some tests without it, and they run fine.

My class starts with

```
public class TransactionTest extends InstrumentationTestCase {
```

The test runs with either:

```
public void testGetDate() throws Exception {
```

or

```
@Test
public void testGetDate() throws Exception {
```

EDIT: It was pointed out that I may be using JUnit 3 tests, but I think I am using JUnit 4:

[image]

Comment: JUnit 4 still provides the classes of JUnit 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@Test 
public void method()

@Test => annotation identifies a method as a test method.
@Test(expected = Exception.class) => Fails if the method does not throw the named exception.
@Test(timeout=100)  =>  Fails if the method takes longer than 100 milliseconds.

@Before 
public void method() =>This method is executed before each test. It is used to prepare the test environment (e.g., read input data, initialize the class).

@After 
public void method() => This method is executed after each test. It is used to cleanup the test environment (e.g., delete temporary data, restore defaults). It can also save memory by cleaning up expensive memory structures.

@BeforeClass 
public static void method() => This method is executed once, before the start of all tests. It is used to perform time intensive activities, for example, to connect to a database. Methods marked with this annotation need to be defined as static to work with JUnit.

@AfterClass 
public static void method() =>  This method is executed once, after all tests have been finished. It is used to perform clean-up activities, for example, to disconnect from a database. Methods annotated with this annotation need to be defined as static to work with JUnit.

@Ignore => Ignores the test method. This is useful when the underlying code has been changed and the test case has not yet been adapted. Or if the execution time of this test is too long to be included.
```

Answer (score 1):

It identifies a method as a test method.  JUnit invokes the class, then it invokes the annotated methods.

If an exception occurs, the test fails; however, you can specify that an exception should occur.  If it does not, the test will fail (testing for the exception - sort of inverse testing):

@Test(expected = Exception.class) - Fails if the method does not throw the named exception.

You can also set time limits and if the function does not finish with the allotted time it will fail:

@Test(timeout = 500) - Fails if the method takes longer than 500 milliseconds.

Comment: Hmm.  With or without \@Test it shows 17 of 17 tests run.  I have 17 functions in the class, so it seems like they run even without \@Test

Comment: The @Test annotation indicates that the public void method to which the test method is attached can be run as a test case without extending TestCase.  I assume (since your test class was not shown) that your class is extending TestCase which is JUnit 3.  In JUnit 4, you don't have to.  Try taking that off and see if all the tests pass.

It also allows for the addition of other annotations, like @Before/@BeforeClass and @After/@AfterClass.  You don't get that option with JUnit 3.  It's more flexible.

Comment: Not only do you not have to extend TestCase in a JUnit4-style test, but if you do you, many features (like Rules, timeouts and expected exceptions) won't work.

Answer (score 1):

In JUnit 4 the `@Test` annotation is used to tell JUnit that a specific method is a test. In JUnit 3 in contrast every method is a test if its name starts with `test` and its class extends `TestCase`.

I assume that InstrumentationTestCase extends `junit.framework.TestCase`. This means that you're using a JUnit 4 annotation within a JUnit 3 test. In this case the tool that runs the tests (your IDE or build tool like Ant or Maven) decides whether is recognizes the `@Test` annotation or not. You can verify this by renaming `testGetDate()` to something that doesn't start with `test`, e.g. `shouldReturnDate()`.  If your tool still runs 17 tests than you know that it supports JUnit 4 annotations within JUnit 3 tests. If it runs 16 tests than you know that the `@Test` annotation is just a flashbang that does nothing.

JUnit 4 still provides the classes of JUnit 3 (the `junit.framework` package). This means you can use JUnit 3 style tests with JUnit 4.

Comment: Don't extend junit.framework.TestCase or use any other class from the  junit.framework package.

Answer (score 0):

In JUnit Annotations are used to give a meaning to a method or class as per test execution point of view. Once you use @Test annotation with a method then that method is not longer an ordinary method it is a Test Case and it will be Executed as Test Case by IDE and JUnit will diplay its execution results as per test case passed or mail on the basis of your assertions.

In case you are starting with JUnit as a beginner do check out simple Junit Tutorial here - http://qaautomated.blogspot.in/p/junit.html